# ColdFusion - output JavaScript for use with Highchart.js

Tags: regex, coldfusion, highcharts

I have a JSON string which I'm passing to a function.
The string is dynamically generated and may contain different "name" parameters.
It looks like this (formatted for easier reading):

```
<cfset x = "
    series: [
       {
           name:inbounds,
           data:
              [
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,1),0],
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,2),0],
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,3),0]
              ]
       },
       {
           name:outbounds,
           data:
              [
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,1),0],
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,2),0],
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,3),0]
              ]
       },
       {
           name:api,
           data:
              [
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,1),441],
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,2),441],
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,3),443]
              ]
       },
       {
           name:excess,
           data:
              [
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,1),0],
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,2),0],
                 [Date.UTC(2012,4,3),0]
              ]
       }
    ] 
">
```

However, I need the value of the "name" parameter to have single quotes around it, 
e.g. Instead of `name:inbounds`, I need `name:'inbounds'`
So, I need something that will search through this string, locate the name parameter and put single quotes around its value.

### EDIT

THe reason I'm doing it this way is because after I call serializeJSON on an array, it generates the following (shorted for snapshot):

```
[{"NAME":"Excess","DATA":[["Date.UTC(2012,5,1)",0],......
```

CF puts everything in double quotes. THe Highcharts API I'm using doesn't want it like this.
So, I get rid of the double quotes with

```
<cfset x = replace(x, """", "", "all")>
```

Then I need to add back single quotes on the string vars.

If there's a better way, I'm open to it.

Comment: CF puts "everything" in quotes because: a) the key names in JSON are *supposed* to be quoted; that's part of the spec; b) "Date.UTC(2012,5,1)" *is* a string, so it should have quotes around it.  That you want it to not be a string is neither here nor there: CF is doing the correct thing here. As for capitalisation, if you create your struct with dot-notation (`myStruct.myKey`) then the keys get uppercased in the struct. If you want case-sensitive keys, use associative array notation (`myStruct["myKey"]`).  I'm afraid the only thing that seems off here are your expectations of how JSON works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do it with Regex then this should work

```
reReplace(json, "\bname\b.*?:([^,]+)", "name:'\1'", "All")
```

Comment: That'll incorrectly quote the value of a key such as `enamel`, would cause problems if there was something like `details:'the x.y should be renamed to x:y'`, assumes the name item is never last/alone, and so on.

Comment: Actually, because of the over-inclusive `.*` that'll not just not work on edge cases - it'll very likely break even with the example provided!

Comment: @baynezy you might wanna tighten-up that regex a bit further so that it matches [^,}] for the value part, just in case - as Peter says - the NAME key is the last one in its struct.  That said, we've no reason to think this will be the case given the info provided by user460114... I think Peter *might* be possibly identifying a problem we don't know to be relevant. But given these variables *could* exist, I am kinda thinking string manipulation via regex might not be the best approach here.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've edited the OP to answer the questions concerning my reason for doing it this way. If there's a better solution, I'm open to it.

Comment: Tried the regex. It seems to work only for the first instance of "name", leaving the others without single quotes around them.

Comment: Solved, just need an "ALL" in there

Answer (score 4):

> *"The string is dynamically generated"*.

Add the single quotes at this point.

(If you're having trouble with that, post the code for it and we can solve that problem.)

Doing it afterwards with regex is not the ideal solution.

**Update:** Now that we have more information on what you're actually doing...

Here is a proof-of-concept for code that converts CF data to a JS string for use with Highcharts.

It is a *partial* solution - I have not gone through the whole [Highcharts API](http://highcharts.com/ref), some of the code below is only half implemented, and some bits might want to be done differently, but in general it should give an idea of how this could work.

If you (and/or anyone else) wanted to take the code below and expand it into a highcharts.cfc, I'm sure it is something which could be useful for the CFML community...

---

#### Code:

```
<cffunction name="convertToHighchartsJs" returntype="String" output=false >
    <cfargument name="CfData" type="Struct" required />

    <cfif NOT StructKeyExists(Arguments.CfData,'Series')>
        <cfthrow message="Does not look like Highcharts data" />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn "series:#serializeForHighcharts(Arguments.CfData.Series)#" />
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="serializeForHighcharts" returntype="String" output=false >
    <cfargument name="Data"       type="any"    required />
    <cfargument name="Name"       type="String" optional />
    <cfargument name="ParentName" type="String" optional />

    <cfset var JsString = "UNABLE TO SERIALIZE" />

    <cfif isStruct(Arguments.Data) >
        <cfsavecontent variable="JsString"><cfoutput><!---
            --->{<!---
                ---><cfloop item="local.CurItem" collection=#Arguments.Data#><!---
                    --->,#fixCase(CurItem)#:#serializeForHighcharts(Arguments.Data[CurItem],CurItem)#<!---
                ---></cfloop><!---
            --->}<!---
        ---></cfoutput></cfsavecontent>

        <cfset JsString = rereplace(JsString,'^\{,','{') />

    <cfelseif isArray(Arguments.Data) >

        <cfsavecontent variable="JsString"><cfoutput><!---
            --->[<!---
                ---><cfloop index="local.CurItem" array=#Arguments.Data#><!---
                    --->,#serializeForHighcharts(CurItem)#<!---
                ---></cfloop><!---
            --->]<!---
        ---></cfoutput></cfsavecontent>

        <cfset JsString = rereplace(JsString,'^\[,','[') />

    <cfelseif isSimpleValue(Arguments.Data) >

        <cfset var ShouldBeQuoted = false />

        <cfif StructKeyExists(Arguments,'Name')>
            <cfif ListFindNoCase('name,text,renderTo,type,color,layout,align,verticalalign',Arguments.Name)>
                <cfset ShouldBeQuoted = true />
            </cfif>

        <cfelseif StructKeyExists(Arguments,'ParentName') AND ListFindNoCase('categories',Arguments.ParentName) />
            <cfset ShouldBeQuoted = true />

        </cfif>

        <cfif ShouldBeQuoted >
            <cfset JsString = "'" & JsStringFormat(Arguments.Data) & "'" />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset JsString = Arguments.Data />
        </cfif>

    </cfif>

    <cfreturn JsString />
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="fixCase" returntype="String" output="false" access="private">
    <cfargument name="Text" type="String" required />

    <cfif NOT StructKeyExists(Variables,'Camels')>
        <cflock type="exclusive" name="regen_camels" timeout=10>
            <cfset Variables.Camels = StructNew() />
            <cfloop index="CurCamel" list="dataParser,dataURL,legendIndex,xAxis,yAxis">
                <cfset Variables.Camels[CurCamel] = CurCamel />
            </cfloop>
        </cflock>
    </cfif>

    <cfif StructKeyExists(Variables.Camels,Arguments.Text)>
        <cfreturn Variables.Camels[Arguments.Text] />
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn Lcase(Arguments.Text) />
    </cfif>

</cffunction>
```

#### Testing:

```
<cfset CfData =
    { 'Series':
        [
            { 'name':'inbounds'
            , 'data':
                [ ['Date.UTC(2012,4,1)',0]
                , ['Date.UTC(2012,4,2)',0]
                , ['Date.UTC(2012,4,3)',0]
                ]
            }
        ,
            { 'name':'outbounds'
            , 'data':
                [ ['Date.UTC(2012,4,1)',0]
                , ['Date.UTC(2012,4,2)',0]
                , ['Date.UTC(2012,4,3)',0]
                ]
            }
        ]
    } />

<cfset Expected = "series:[{name:'inbounds',data:[[Date.UTC(2012,4,1),0],[Date.UTC(2012,4,2),0],[Date.UTC(2012,4,3),0]]},{name:'outbounds',data:[[Date.UTC(2012,4,1),0],[Date.UTC(2012,4,2),0],[Date.UTC(2012,4,3),0]]}]" />


<cfset JsString = convertToHighchartsJs(CfData) />

<cfif JsString EQ Expected>
    <h1 style="color:green">Matches</h1>
<cfelse>
    <h1 style="color:red">different</h1>
</cfif>

<cfdump var=#{Received:JsString,Expected:Expected}# />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of your problem here is that string you have in your variable `x` *isn't* JSON: it doesn't conform to the [JSON schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

So the best thing to do here, rather than try to fix it after the fact, is to make sure it's well-formed from the outset.

As @Peter touched on, if you are in control of the creation of the string, then do it right to start with.  If you get it from a third party, get in touch with them and point this out, and they might just fix it.

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your string as you go, to make sure you're doing it right.

Comment: Yeah, in this case it isn't actually supposed to be json. It's the format required by HighCharts. SerializeJSON is simply a convenient way to transform a complex coldfusion array/struct combination into a javascript/ajax usable format. I just wish it didn't take it upon itself to add quotes around things you didn't ask it to, changing your single quotes to double quotes and upper casing everything.

Comment: SerializeJSON is a way to serialiaze a CF object into a JSON string. It isn't designed to handle JS code, and your assumption that it does is what is causing these problems. (p.s. The uppercasing is done by CF, not serializeJson.)